# Почему не работает телеграм-бот?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

пробую создать первого бота при помощи телеграфа, взял с их гитхаба код:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(config.token)

bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome!'))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Send me a sticker'))
bot.on('sticker', (ctx) => ctx.reply(''))
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'))
bot.launch()
```

сделал всё по инструкции, создал бота в тг, скопировал токен, создал папку для бота, пока что решил на сервер не заливать, пока что просто для себя делаю. в папку инициализировал npm, добавил сам телеграф. токен прописал через создание config.json а в нем прописал сам токен. далее через терминал указываю: `node index.js` чтобы запустить бота, но ничего не происходит, терминал указывает на то, что работает, но сам бот при этом не реагирует. что я делаю не так?

Comment: быть может вы будете всё дебажить? **bot.start((ctx) => {console.log('start bot..');})**

Comment: @MoloF ну задебажил. добавил вместо `bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome!'))` вот это вот: `bot.start((ctx) => {console.log('start bot..');})` повторил всё. в лог ничего не пришло

Comment: bot.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Ooops', err)
})

Comment: @MoloF консоль опять молчит.. код выглядит следующим образом `const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const config = require('./config.json');

const bot = new Telegraf(config.token);
bot.start((ctx) => {console.log('start bot..');});
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome!'));
bot.catch((err) => { console.log('Ooops', err) })
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Send me a sticker'));
bot.on('sticker', (ctx) => ctx.reply(''));
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'));
bot.launch();`

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема была в том, что роскомпараша заблокировала телеграм. я загрузил бота на сервер и всё моментально заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно использовать VPN..